# wolframalpha conditional solving

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I try to put the following expression, but it cannot recognize the condition(assumptions). How can it be done?

```
solve[(abs[y-x]  +abs[z-x] +  abs[y-z]  )   z, y, x Assumptions ->    x<y<0<z]
```

Comment: `Solve` needs an equation with an `=` but you don't have that. Does this help: `Simplify abs[y-x]+abs[z-x]+abs[y-z] assuming x<y<0<z` which WA understands and returns `2z-2x` That still doesn't solve for `x,y,z` but maybe that is simple enough that you can tell what the solution should be.

Comment: @Bill thank you. What about finding value of x such as  solving abs[abs[-x]+abs[2x+1]+5x]] assuming x<-1/2? Can you help?

Comment: @Bill I try wa to show step by step simplifying the given expression such abs[-x-2x-1+5x] = abs[2x-1] = -2x+1. Actually I want to see these steps

Comment: Ah... now I understand. Thank you. I do not know how many of the steps that WA will show when using simplify, but simplify seems closest to what you want it to do.